# How to get TestSet ID using Rally Rest API in Java?

Tags: java, rally

I am using following code to get TestSet ID. But it doesn't give any result

```
QueryRequest testsetRequest = new QueryRequest("Test Set");
testsetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
testsetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestSet.Name", "=", "TestSetName"));
QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testsetRequest);
System.out.println(String.format("\nTestSet:%d",testSetQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount()));
StringTestSetref=testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").toString();
System.out.println(TestSetref);
```

Comment: You have a space in `new QueryRequest("Test Set")`. Is that correct?

Comment: I have also tried without space. then also it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting an error in your query.  Code like this should work. The else clause will also help you diagnose what errors you are getting if there is a problem with your query.

```
QueryRequest testsetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestSet"); //no spaces
testsetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));     

//No need to specify type again 
testsetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "TestSetName")); 
QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testsetRequest);

if(testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
    for (JsonElement result : testSetQueryResponse.getResults()) {
        //handle results
    }
} else {
    //See what error occurred
    for (String err : testSetQueryResponse.getErrors()) {
        System.err.println("\t" + err);
    }
}
```