# How to update test results in rally api by providing test set name

Tags: java, rest, api, rally

I tried with the code in the below previous post .

[How to get TestSet ID using Rally Rest API in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819433/how-to-get-testset-id-using-rally-rest-api-in-java)

i am able to update test results in rally api by providing test set id ,but when I provide test set name , i am getting null pointer exception. I am able to retrieve the test set id for first two iterations , but when creating test case ,test set is null . Do i need to change query parameter ? ,. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help?

Comment: Hi Kyle ,I use the below code.                                                                   QueryRequest testsetRequest = new QueryRequest("Test Set"); testsetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name")); testsetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestSet.Name", "=", "TestSetName")); QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testsetRequest); System.out.println(String.format("\nTestSet:%d",testSetQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount())); StringTestSetref=testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").toString(); System.out.println(TestSetref);

Answer (score 0):

There are a few updates to the code you provided that allow getting this information.  The updates are:

```
QueryRequest testsetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestSet");
testsetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
testsetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "TestSetName"));
QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testsetRequest);
System.out.println(String.format("\nTestSet: %d",testSetQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount()));
String TestSetref = testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").toString();
System.out.println(TestSetref);
```

Comment: Hi michael , i used the above code , but still I am getting ,null pointer exception on create request ,but I am able to fetch object I'd from test set response